# How to modify only day of the month in python?

Tags: python-3.x, date

Below snippet would provide current date:
import datetime
from datetime import date

```
today_date = date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

However, if i want to create another variable 'abc' with day of the month fixed as 10 but pull month and year from 'today_date', how can i do that?
Example if today_date is 20201109, i want 'abc' as 20201110. If i run this code on say 16th Dec, i want 'abc' to be 20201210.

I tried below code:
df["today_date"].map(lambda x: x.replace(date=10))

But getting this error:
TypeError: replace() takes no keyword arguments

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [replace](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html) method.

```
>>> today_date = date.today().replace(day=10).strftime('%Y%m%d')
>>> today_date
'20201110'
```

If your input is a dataframe what you could do is

```
df['today_date'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(day=10))
```